# Save Cv2 video file to another location

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

I have a script that record the webcam in the background using python, but I want to save the clip to a specific directory, I was wondering if there's any way that I could do that

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # Começa a gravar
out = cv2.VideoWriter('Teste.avi', -1, 20.0, (640, 480))

   

if cam.isOpened(): # Camera on ou não
    op, frame = cam.read()
else:
    op = False


while op:

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('x'): # Para o programa
        break

cam.release()
```

Comment: ``import os; cv2.VideoWriter(os.path.join('<write-path>','Teste.avi'), -1, 20.0, (640, 480))``

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # Começa a gravar
# out = cv2.VideoWriter('Teste.avi', -1, 20.0, (640, 480))
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('path//of//location//output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while (cam.isOpened()):
    op,frame = cam.read()
    if (op == True):
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('x'):
            break

    else:
        break

cam.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If you have any doubt, you can refer to the [documentation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
your_path = "location where you want to save"
try:
    os.mkdir(your_path)
except:
    pass #directory already there
out = cv2.VideoWriter(your_path+'/output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
```